# OS X 10.11.6 can not update iTunes 12.5.1, app store problem

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore

As shown in picture, app store tell me to update iTunes 12.5.1, but in updates installed list, you can see I have already installed iTunes 12.5.1. But actually, my iTunes version is still 12.4.3 Now, I click the update button of iTunes, then after download completed, nothing will install, and return this page to wait update. My mac os x system is 10.11.6

[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. I ran Disk Utility -> First Aid and it found a buch of issues. After that I was able to download iTune 12.5.1 properly.

If that doesn't work, you can always download it directly from: http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

Comment: Thanks, I download it directly from website and install, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work, all I did was download iTunes from the Apple site and installed it via the new DMG file.